# unknown word (csssyntaxerror)stylelint(csssyntaxerror) in .env file

Tags: reactjs

how can I fix this error(unknown word (csssyntaxerror)stylelint(csssyntaxerror) ) in my .env file in react app. ,I did not change anything in it but when i started my app this error appeared

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem has appeared when the vs code added the ("") mark to the value of REACT_APP_........variable
[image]

..that made a problem in (process.env) and axios

when I removed the ("")
[image]

the app ran again